# Phonegap Build - window.open not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to implement a simple Hyperlink-Image into my Android-App that is being build using Phonegap Build. However, the Javascript-Line which is supposed to open the Link in the device-internal Browser seems not to be working.

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/", '_system',  'location=yes');
```

When the Code is executed, nothing happens and no error is produced either.
My config.xml-file looks like this:

```
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.test.testapp"
    versionCode = "10"
    version     = "1.0.0" >


<name>Testapp</name>

<description>
    App for testing
</description>


<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>

<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" spec="0.6.0" source="pgb" />



<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
</widget>
```

I also made sure to include the latest cordova.js in my html-file.

What can I do to make the Code work?

Answer (score 0):

@user1638628,

Your questions is *What can I do to make the Code work?*

1. Read the blog posts. [Phonegap Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/) – and – *[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/)*
2. Read the documentation. [InAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)
3. Start with examples in the documentation.

#### To Fix your issues

1. I am going to rewrite you `config.xml`. It's easier
2. In the future, your going to have to apply the `whitelist` on your own.
   Read [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md). Make sure you apply the `CSP` to your index.html (in the future; not needed here).
3. Instead of `_system` you want to use `_self`, see [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).
4. Your making common mistake. Please read [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
       <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
           xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
           id          = "com.test.testapp"
           versionCode = "10"
           version     = "1.0.0" >
       <name>Testapp</name>
       <description>App for testing</description>

       <!-- The plugin works for Android and iOS -->
       <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />

       <allow-navigation href="*" />
       <allow-intent href="*" />
       <access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
   </widget>
   ```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response and the helpful links.

I tried to use your version of the config.xml and the targets "_blank", "_self" and "_system" and using the snippet:

    " navigator.app.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/", { openExternal: true }); "

but the hyperlinks still do nothing while not producing errors or messages.

Comment: @user1638628  Please update your post with your new code. make sure to make a note at the bottom that you did so. Then respond. My impression is you are skipping something. Make sure to write a reply so I know you have done this. TIA